# Does a CocoaPod require all dependencies to be CocoaPods as well?

Tags: ios, github, cocoapods

I have a project which I want to make a `CocoaPod` of. This project requires three other projects which I am now bringing in as independent frameworks.

```
FrameWorks1 :=> github.com/f1
FrameWorks2 :=> github.com/f2
FrameWorks3 :=> github.com/f3
```

While writing the `podspec` for my project, I found that `FrameWorks3` does not have a `podspec` inside it. So I tried to add it in like this:

```
s.framework = 'FrameWorks3'
```

But how do I add the source code link to it now? Do I just add the source code as part of my project? Say I don't want it here and wish to add it as a `pod`, does this mean that now I have to go and submit a `.podspec` to `github.com/f3` or is there any easier solution here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Fork that independent frameworks.
2. Configure `.podspec`s for them.
3. Add them as your's local pods with

   `pod 'Framework1', :path => '~/Path/To/Folder/Containing/Framework1/Fork'
   pod 'Framework2', :path => '~/Path/To/Folder/Containing/Framework2/Fork'
   pod 'Framework3', :path => '~/Path/To/Folder/Containing/Framework3/Fork'`
4. Now all should be ok.
5. If you want to update framework to new release - just pull changes into fork (don't forget to update `.podspec` after that).
6. If you want - make pull requests to frameworks original repositories. If their owners find it useful - they'll approve it, no - you'll be fine with forked versions.

**Part 2**

To make it independent from yours local machine, you can create yours own podspec repository:

1. Create empty git repository for podspecs (with address like `https://github.com/user/xpodspecs.git`).
2. Add that repo to CocoaPods: `pod repo add xpodspecs https://github.com/user/xpodspecs.git`.
3. For each custom podspecs you created, push them to yours podspec repo: `pod push xpodspecs Framework1`.
4. Now, anytime you or your's teammates need to pull that custom pods, you just add your's podspec repo to CocoaPods: `pod repo add xpodspecs https://github.com/user/xpodspecs.git`

*More detailed info is [here](http://pablin.org/2013/05/18/cocoapods-for-internal-libraries/).*